# How to segregate recurring jobs in Hangfire between two services

Tags: c#, job-scheduling, hangfire

I have two different services that use the same `Hangfire` instance for scheduling recurring jobs. I am using 1 `Hangfire` dashboard. Service 1 adds one recurring job, while Service 2 adds three recurring jobs. The issue is that all three jobs from Service 2 are being executed within the scope of Service 1. I want to find a solution to ensure that the first job is executed in the scope of Service 1, while the three jobs added by Service 2 are executed in the scope of Service 2.

How can I configure `Hangfire` to correctly execute the recurring jobs added by Service 1 and Service 2 within their respective scopes, ensuring that the jobs from Service 2 do not interfere with those from Service 1?

Comment: You can use Hangfire's support for multiple queues and background job filters.

Answer (score 0):

By using different queues for each service, you ensure that jobs from Service 1 and Service 2 are kept separate and executed independently.

```
using Hangfire;

public class MyJobService
{
    public void ScheduleJobForService1()
    {
        // Add a job to "service1" queue
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => YourJobMethod(), new EnqueuedState { Queue = "service1" });

        // Schedule a recurring job for Service 1 in "service1" queue
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => YourRecurringJobMethod(), Cron.Daily, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, "service1");
    }

    public void ScheduleJobForService2()
    {
        // Add a job to "service2" queue
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => YourJobMethod(), new EnqueuedState { Queue = "service2" });

        // Schedule recurring jobs for Service 2 in "service2" queue
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => YourRecurringJobMethod(), Cron.Hourly, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, "service2");
    }

    public void YourJobMethod()
    {
        // Your job logic here
    }

    public void YourRecurringJobMethod()
    {
        // Your recurring job logic here
    }
}
```